# Kotlin QueryDsl not generating Q classes

Tags: kotlin, querydsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using kts gradle with koltin. However when i try to add QueryDsl it's not genetation Q classes from my JPA entities.

My build.gradle.kts looks like:

```
plugins {
  id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.1.RELEASE"
  id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
  kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.72"
  kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.72"
  kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.0"
  kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.10"
} 

dependencies {
  // some spring boot dependencies here...
  implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
  kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:general")
}

kapt {
 annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor")
}
```

I suggest it should build Q classes to `build/generated/source/kapt/main`. Any ideas why it's not working?
Also tried to annotate my entity with `@QueryEntity` annotation. Not working as well

Comment: `kotlin("jvm")` and `kotlin("kapt")` have different versions. Will it work if you unify versions for all gradle kotlin plugins?

Comment: Having the same issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: @MartinSchüller yes, posted an answer, hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed by adding next configuration

```
// quert dsl
implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.1")
kapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.2:jpa")
annotationProcessor(group = "com.querydsl", name = "querydsl-apt", classifier = "jpa")
```

Also i removed

```
annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor")
```